# Quitting my stressful job but I am in the quarter of a project and still bond in a contract

Tags: professionalism, management, work-environment, project-management, work-life-balance

I'm currently engaged on a contract with another year remaining - the project is very stressful however (with a demanding client, a boss with high expectations and a team that seems to be disengaged and lacking in urgency despite the deadlines) so I'm looking to quit as I can't take the stress any more.

What would be the best way to quit as soon as possible with out ruining my reputation with my boss and the company?

Comment: [What are the repercussions on my career of quitting a contract job before it expires?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/9259)

Comment: This does not seem to be a question. Can you explain what specific problem you want us to address?

Comment: I've edited your question to try and clarify what you are asking and bring this on topic for the Workplace, hopefully I've preserved your intent but if not feel free to revert the edit or do one of your own.

Comment: @Dukeling This is a duplicate, but not of that question. The user wants to know the best way to quit, not what the ramifications could be

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resign without burning bridges when I'm a critical staff member?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/56611/how-do-i-resign-without-burning-bridges-when-im-a-critical-staff-member)

Comment: @Dukeling Amazing how you can find these so quick, my search skills are terrible on these sites!

Comment: It depends on the term specified in the contract. You may need to take legal opinion in this case. It also depends on the labour rules in your country.

Comment: Stress usually comes from within.
From your posting, i gather, you are in the project manager position.
I would suggest using  time management tools to follow, update and review the entire project.
Having all this at your disposal, you can evaluate resources and report to your superiors any issue and proposed solutions. Timeline will follow naturally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's going to be **very** difficult to extract yourself from this contract without at least some impact on your reputation with this boss/company as it's almost inevitably going to impact upon delivery/meeting deadlines.

I would suggest at least giving your boss a chance to resolve the issues (even if you don't really believe it is possible).

The best approach would be to have a 1-1 meeting with your manager as soon as you can and just be honest - explain the issues you're facing and that you don't feel that you can continue in this way. Your boss *might* be able to take some actions or have some suggestions that will make the situation tolerable for you and if they do I'd suggest at least giving them a shot - it may work and if it doesn't then at least you've shown a willingness to *try* which should count for a lot. And if they don't work out (or if they don't even try to change it themselves) then you can explain that you are sorry but that it's just not working out and you can discuss an exit plan that would be inline with your contractual obligations (I'm assuming there must be some kind of break clause) and would minimize impact on the project and company.